# Filter Laravel timestamp by day

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Filter Laravel timestamp by day

Hello. There is a model with a table that stores data for every 15 minutes, you need to get data for a year / month, only 1 record for each day.
And the same must be done with the hour. And it is desirable to display the average number for this hour / day.
Are there any options?

Answer (score 0):

To get the average number for each day, you can use the groupBy() and avg() methods in Laravel's query builder. Here's an example:

```
    $year = 2023;
    $month = 6;
    
    $data = Data::whereYear('created_at', $year)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
                ->groupBy(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
                ->select(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), \DB::raw('AVG(number) as average'))
                ->get();
```

To get the average number for each hour, you can modify the query as follows:

```
$data = Data::whereYear('created_at', $year)
            ->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
            ->groupBy(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), 
               \DB::raw('HOUR(created_at)'))
            ->select(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), \DB::raw('HOUR(created_at) as hour'), \DB::raw('AVG(number) as average'))
            ->get();
```